# Laravel 5.4 and datatables plugin: slow loading

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm using laravel 5.4 and datatables plugin. I´m using datatables from paginate, orderby and search in the views of an admin panel. But the plugin is very slow with a table of 7000 records.

In the controller, I tried to show ther records: `dd($data['noticias']);` and this is fast, but in the view with datatables it takes several minutes!

I've seen some answers but they don´t fit what I'm doing, they use Ajax and I don´t know nothing about ajax. How can I solve the slow load? Thanks.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['noticias'] = Noticia::with('langs')->get();
    $data['sections']  = Section::all();
    $data['positions']  = Position::all();

    return view('panel.noticias.index', compact('data'));
}
```

View:

```
<table id="listados" class="table table-striped" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]' data-page-length='25'>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="96">Fecha</th>
        <th data-orderable='false' width="60">Hora</th>
        <th>Título</th>
        <th style="min-width:100px">Sección</th>
        <th data-orderable='false' width="60">Fotos</th>
        <th align="center" width="60">Ancla</th>
        <th data-orderable='false' align="right" width="180">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

@foreach($data['noticias'] as $new)
    <tr>

        <td>{!! date('Y-m-d', strtotime($new->date)) !!}</td>
        <td>{!! date('H:i', strtotime($new->time)) !!}</td>

        <td>
            @foreach($new->langs as $new_lang)
                @include('panel.partials.list_name', ['value' => $new_lang, 'route' => 'noticias.edit', 'id' => $new->id, 'name' => $new_lang->title])
            @endforeach
        </td>

        <td>
             @foreach($data['sections'] as $section)
                @if($section->id == $new->section_id)
                    {!! $section->name !!}
                @endif
             @endforeach
        </td>

        <td align="center">
            {!! (count($new->images) == 0) ? '' : count($new->images) !!}
        </td>

        <td align="center">
            @foreach($data['positions'] as $position)
                @if($position->id == "1")
                    <span class="position">
                    {!! ($position->pos1 == $new->id) ? '[ 1 ]' : ''  !!}
                    {!! ($position->pos2 == $new->id) ? '[ 2 ]' : ''  !!}
                    {!! ($position->pos3 == $new->id) ? '[ 3 ]' : ''  !!}
                    {!! ($position->pos4 == $new->id) ? '[ 4 ]' : ''  !!}
                    {!! ($position->pos5 == $new->id) ? '[ 5 ]' : ''  !!}
                    </span>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </td>

        <td align="right">
            <a href="{{ route('noticias.update-active', $new->id) }}"> @include('panel.partials.list_active', ['value' => $new->active]) </a>
            @include('panel.partials.list_edit', ['route' => 'noticias.edit', 'id' =>$new->id])
            @include('panel.partials.list_image', ['route' => 'noticias.dropzone', 'id' =>$new->id])
            @include('panel.partials.list_show', ['route' => 'noticia', 'id' =>$new->id, 'slug' =>$new_lang->slug])
            @include('panel.partials.list_delete', ['route' => 'noticias.delete', 'id' =>$new->id])
        </td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#listados').DataTable({

    "pageLength": 25,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]],

    "language": {
        "paginate":
            {
                "previous": "←",
                "next": "→"
            },
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "decimal": ",",
        "thousands": ".",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar:  _MENU_",
        "zeroRecords": "No se ha encontrado nada",
        "info": "[ _START_ - _END_ de <strong>_TOTAL_</strong> ]",
        "infoEmpty": "No hay registros",
        "infoFiltered": "<i>— filtrados de _MAX_</i>"
    }
});
});
```

I have included the cdns:

```
{!! HTML::style('https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css') !!}

{!! HTML::script('https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') !!}
```

Comment: is it works slowly with the same query on the database? have you defined all indexes for your query conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is slow just because it is not server side pagination. What is happens is that you get all the 7000 records and after that the jquery plugin will change the dom to work with client side pagination. What i recommend using is this https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables .

This plugin is a laravel wrapper for datatables and it will work with server side pagination. So when you will change the page it will send a new ajax request to an endpoint on your app to get that specific page data, so will will query the database for only few rows instead of all of them.

**Transformers**

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal , it takes a collection or a collectionItem and it changes the data, so if you need to change your model in some way just for few responses, you can do it with this.

Real world fast example is that if you want to send a user instance you can use a transformer to just send username and email on the response, without the password and id or other fields that you have on your User model etc.

**Datatables plugin transformer link:** http://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/response-fractal

Comment: Thanks from the clarification Munteanu Petrisor. I will integrate it.

Comment: You will need to read about Transformers too , as i see that your data on a column is more complex

Comment: What is Transformers? Can you tell me where I find information?

Comment: Thaks again. It's a bit complex for me. I'll start installing the plugin and when it works, I'll look at the transformers.

Comment: Reading through the plugin documentation it will help you a lot

Comment: Well, I still have not been able to prove it, but I can see that this is the correct answer. And, in my case, yes I need the transformer. Thanks Munteanu Petrisor.